# Prove $\det(A+BC) = \det(A) (1+CA^{-1}B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Assume $A_{n \times n}$ is an invertible matrix, $B$ is a vector and $C$ is a row vector.

How can we prove that $\det(A+BC) = \det(A) (1+CA^{-1}B)$?

I tried proving it using the statement proved in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811433/let-m-big-beginsmallmatrix-a-b-c-d-endsmallmatrix-big-prove) $\det(M) = \det(A) \cdot \det(D-C A^{-1} B)$ (which was presented to me in the similar questions while posting this question), but had no success. I would be grateful if a proof can be made using the statement proved in the linked question.

Comment: Note: this result is sometimes referred to as the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Comment: @Jigsaw What you need is the following general result: let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m \leqslant n$, $\mathbf{A}$ be a *commutative* ring and $M \in \mathscr{M}_{m, n}(\mathbf{A})$ respectively $N \in \mathscr{M}_{n, m}(\mathbf{A})$ two rectangular matrices. Then the following relation holds between the characteristic polynomials of $MN$ and $NM$: $\det(X\mathrm{I}_n-NM)=X^{n-m}\det(X\mathrm{I}_m-MN)$.

Comment: [Weinstein–Aronszajn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein–Aronszajn_identity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we have
$$
\det(A + BC) = \det(A[I + A^{-1}BC]) = \det(A)\det(I + [A^{-1}B]C).
$$
with $U = A^{-1}B$ and $V = C$, it suffices to show that
$$
\det(I + UV) = 1 + VU.
$$
This can be seen as an instance of the [W-A identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity). One proof of this result is given in the linked page.

---

If you're still set on using the linked result, we can indeed prove this result as a consequence. Let $M$ denote the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{A & -B\\ C & 1}.
$$
If we apply the linked result directly to this matrix, then we have
$$
\det(M) = \det(A)\det(D - CA^{-1}(-B)) = \det(A)(1 + CA^{-1}B).
$$
On the other hand, we note that
$$
\det \pmatrix{A & -B\\ C & 1} = 
(-1)^{n-1}\det\pmatrix{-B & A\\ 1 & C} = 
[(-1)^{n-1}]^2\det\pmatrix{1 & C\\ -B & A}.
$$
That is, we have
$$
\det(M) = \det\pmatrix{1 & C\\ -B & A}.
$$
Applying the linked result to this matrix yields
$$
\det\pmatrix{1 & C\\ B & A} = \det(1)\det(A - (-B)1^{-1}C) = \det(A + BC).
$$
So, we have $\det(A)(1 + CA^{-1}B) = \det(A + BC)$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

$A + B C = A(I + A^{-1} B C)$.  If $S$ and $T$ are $n \times m$ and $m \times n$ matrices,  $ST$ and $TS$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.