# Determinant of order 2 block matrix following specific instructions

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

Given a block matrix of the form
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
A_{11} & A_{12} \\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$$
with $A_{11}$ invertible, I want to prove that $$\det (A) = \det (A_{11}) \det \left(A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}\right)$$ I know this has already been asked and answered several times. The problem is that the exercise says I should first compute the determinant of the following matrices:
$$
A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & 0 \\
0 & I
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
A_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0 \\
0 & A_{22}
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & 0 \\
0 & A_{22}
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
A_4 =\begin{pmatrix}
I & A_{11}^{-1}A_{12} \\
0 & I
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
A_5 =\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\
0 & A_{22}
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
$$
This is obviously pretty easy, but from here on I don't see how to finish the proof. I know that I have to give a specific factorization of $A$ which allows me to calculate its determinant, but I don't know how to do it by using this five matrices.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Schur complement?

Comment: see this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1811480/938462

Comment: Where does this come from? From a textbook?

Comment: @AbolfazlChamanmotlagh thank you!